# Use of undefined constant in submit website

Tags: php, mysql, undefined

I am facing the undefined index problems. I checked my html image code, looks fine.

but it still show the problem when I try to update the page

the main problem of it is when I update the page,

it show something like this

> Notice: Undefined index: image in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cms/admin/includes/edit_post.php
>   on line 31
>
> Notice: Undefined index: image in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cms/admin/includes/edit_post.php
>   on line 32

```
QUERY FAILED .You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '= '2', post_title = 'javascript', post_date = now(), post_author = 'Winter', pos' at line 1
```

So , Im pretty sure I have some syntax problem on those Query line, maybe I forget to add some space in some line?

I believe the function confirm() is fine, it is just a function name.

```
$query ="UPDATE posts SET";
        $query .="post_category_id = '{$post_category_id}', "; 
        $query .="post_title = '{$post_title}', ";
        $query .="post_date = now(), ";
        $query .="post_author = '{$post_author}', ";
        $query .="post_status = '{$post_status}', ";
        $query .="post_tags = '{$post_tags}' , ";
        $query .="post_content = '{$post_content}', ";
        $query .="post_image ='{$post_image}' ";
        $query .="WHERE post_id = {$the_post_id} ";

        $update_post = mysqli_query($connection,$query);


        confirm($update_post);
         //        if(! $update_post) //        die("QUERY FAILED" . mysqli_error($connection));
```

This is the image form-group html code

I checked the name="post_image" they seems match.

And I checked other's question, but still cannot understand why have a notice here.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id = $the_post_id "; 
            $select_posts_by_id = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_posts_by_id)){


            $post_image =  $row['post_image'];


            }

    if(isset($_POST['update_post'])){

            $post_image =  $_FILES['image']['name'];
            $post_image_temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];


        move_uploaded_file($post_image_temp, "../images/$post_image");


}

<div class="form-group">
       <label for="post_image">Post Image</label>
       <img  width="100" src="../images/<?php echo $post_image  ?>" alt="" >
       <input type="file" name="post_image">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Notice: Undefined index: image

it's mean than in input where you upload file it name is 'post_image'

```
<input type="file" name="post_image">
```

than in your php-code you have

```
$post_image =  $_FILES['image']['name'];
$post_image_temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
```

you must change on

```
$post_image =  $_FILES['post_image']['name'];
$post_image_temp = $_FILES['post_image']['tmp_name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
$query ="UPDATE posts SET";
$query .="post_category_id = '{$post_category_id}', ";
```

builds the string `UPDATE posts SETpost_category_id = '...'` and this is the source of the MySQL error.

It is probably also vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (depending where `$post_category_id` comes from and how it is handled before being used to build the query).

I recommend you to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php):

```
$query = "UPDATE posts SET post_category_id=?, post_title=? WHERE post_id=?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'isi', $post_category_id, $post_title, $the_post_id);
$update_post = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Read more on the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).